# How to print PDF file in a Java application?

Tags: java, pdf, printing

How do I print a PDF file from a Java application?

Answer (score 8):

Here some source code that will allow you print any text file:

```
public void print() {
    //The desktop api can help calling other applications in our machine
    //and also many other features...
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try {
    //desktop.print(new File("DocXfile.docx"));
        desktop.print(new File("Docfile.pdf"));
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe it suit your needs since you did not give more details.

Comment: @user234194 i dont think so, but for more info about the Desktop API, have a look at: `http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/`

Answer (score 5):

Try [PDF Renderer](https://github.com/katjas/PDFrenderer). It's open source and there are a couple of examples on the site on how to render to a printer device.

Comment: Link is dead.  The project has been forked here: https://github.com/katjas/PDFrenderer

Comment: The answer is simple.  I forgot that I could. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I've used [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) before for a similar task like yours. 
It's an excellent library from the [Apache Software Foundation](http://www.apache.org/).
The class you are probably going to use is called: *PDFTextStripper* . 
The javadoc for the class can be found [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html).

Comment: _As a side note:_ to print an existing PDF it would be enough to just load it and print, like: `PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("mydoc.pdf")); pdfDocument.print();`. Or use [`pdfDocument.silentPrint()`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#silentPrint()) to print without a prompt. I.e. without ever using PDFTextStripper instance.