# Print pdf in network printer using java

Tags: java, pdf, printing

Guys I am stuck in printing a pdf using java. 
The code that I have written is below:

`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws PrinterException, PrintException, IOException{
        DocFlavor docflavor = new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM ("application/octet-stream");
    //  DocFlavor docflavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
/*      DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.;*/
        PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        DocFlavor[] docF = printService.getSupportedDocFlavors();
        for(int i = 0; i<docF.length;i++){
            System.out.println(docF[i]);
        }
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("pathofpdffile");



        Doc pdfDoc = new SimpleDoc(fis, docflavor, null);


        DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        aset.add(new Copies(1));
        aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
        printJob.print(pdfDoc,aset);

        fis.close();
```

}`

The above code intiate the printing activity but the problem is that I get only encode character in print. I am not able to get my exact file.

Second if I change the DocFlavor to SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE ,it throws an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type
at javax.print.SimpleDoc.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.calculator.main.PrintingTest.main(PrintingTest.java:42)
```

Third IF I change the DocFlavor to INPUT_STREAM.PDF, it throws as error

```
`Exception in thread "main" sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
at com.calculator.main.PrintingTest.main(PrintingTest.java:49)`
```

All this I am trying on a network printer.
Any help would gr8..

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478890/how-to-print-pdf-file-in-a-java-application

Comment: Which framework do you use to parse and print the PDF?

Comment: @RaviH : I am not prefering to use any external jar for this. I too had a walk through the link posted by you. any further help !!!

Comment: @AaronDigulla : framework I didn't get u.. :( . It is plain java code.

Comment: Does it work when you print on a different printer?

Answer (score 12):

Just change your code to use AUTO_SENSE as shown below.

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C://test.pdf");
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that `new DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM ("application/octet-stream")` isn't what you want.

You may want to try the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962278/34088